# Create polygon randomly finishes sketch

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing

When I'm creating a new polygon in ArcGIS Pro, or even in ArcMap, I'll just be clicking along and it will act as if I double clicked and finished the polygon when in fact I did not. This wouldn't be as big of a problem if when it completed, it didn't create a vertex at every point where the line crosses itself. This is a huge problem, I've tried creating new feature classes in new geodatabases but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This sounds like a mouse driver or other system issue. Tech Support might be of assistance, but I don't see how we could be.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse? A mouse of mine started clicking twice when it was worn out so I had to buy a new one :)

Comment: You may try to set the double click setting (on the mouse setting) to require a shorter delay between the two click to act as a double click...